# node/express application started but not listing on any port

Tags: node.js, express

I have below application successfully started but it doesn't listen on port 8080.

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('shanadminpanel:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);
```

When I enter url `localhost:8080`, nothing happened.

Comment: Nothing happens? What error message shows up in the console? Do you have an routes available?

Answer (score 0):

You have use http

So you can create server by any of this .
Two way you can create server

**by http module**

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
console.log("server created") 
}).listen(80);
```

And by express you can do this.

**by express**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World');
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```